# MFC:CDHtmlDialog Purpose/Usages to open other views?

Tags: winapi, mfc

I was thinking of writing a new app where a users selects an option of what procedure they want to perform and the view changes to that until done then goes back to the main menu.   I came across `CDHtmlDialog` and looked like a nice easy way to add a nice looking menu using html.   But I wonder if that is the purpose of that class?  Can I set it up so when a button or graphic link is clicked it changes out the view to another one (I would need to use traditional things like `CTreeView` with `CListView` with a splitter) or is it more for staying within the HTML world?

Thanks.

Comment: I have an MDI application which has to support several different `View` types for the documents being displayed. So I have some code to **switch** the view type, but that is outside he scope of this question concerning the use of  `CDHtmlDialog`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the MSDN [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cdhtmldialog-class?view=msvc-170)
`CDHtmlDialog` Class is used to create dialog boxes that use HTML rather than dialog resources to implement their user interface.

From what I can gather from your post, I think you should consider SDI application using view classes that you want. To switch views on the command you do not need a splitter window. A static splitter is used to display a number of views in a different part of the splitter simultaneously.